# Листинг директории

Tags: java

Подскажите, как написать программу, которая делает список всех файлов и папок в данной (как параметр командной строки) папке (включая подпапки).

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Давно уже никак не могу найти простейший способ решения (в две-три строчки). Мне тож интересно

Comment: ну может поможете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К ответу от @Петрович.

Вам надо определиться с основами Java, а уже потом за обзор директорий браться :)

AAAAA.java

```
class AAAAA {
    public static void traverse(File directory) {
        System.out.println(directory);

        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : directory.listFiles()) {
                traverse(child);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        traverse(new File("/какой/нибудь/путь/на/диске"));
    }
}
```

Comment: ну напишите мне пожалуйста полностью!!!! я буду по гроб жизни благодарна!!!

Comment: Обновил. Загробные благодарности - плохой стафф :)

Comment: traverse(new File("/какой/нибудь/путь/на/диске");
РУГАЕТСЯ НА ;

Comment: не работает!!!

Comment: Скобку забыл закрыть. Исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Если это нужно для решения другой задачи - воспользуйтесь [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). А если это и есть задача - хм, ну [посмотрите](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/io/trunk), как это сделали коммитеры Apache :)

Comment: это и есть задача и не знаю как сделать

Answer (score 2):

В таком духе:

```
public static void traverse(File directory) {
    System.out.println(directory);

    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : directory.listFiles()) {
            traverse(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а далее как? 
очень трудно девушкам это!

Comment: А далее смотря, что вы хотите делать. Этот пример просто выводит на экран все папки и подпапки начиная с указанной в File directory.

Comment: А что дальше? Это и есть само решение. "очень трудно девушкам это" - не надо сказок, всё вы можете :)

Comment: а как сам класс написать чтобы скомпилить?